# How are sessions managed in Java based desktop applications?

Tags: java, session, desktop-application

I am new to java desktop applications. I have done web programming in java where we get to handle sessions by HttpSession.
I would like to know about how exactly is session management done for java based desktop applications?

Answer (score 0):

Actually , you can use Apache Shiro framework, It supports session management in Desktop applications besides Web Applications and many other security stuff.[Check this out](http://shiro.apache.org/index.html)